# preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'c'

Tags: php

i get this error in my code:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'c' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper.php on line 6
```

Can you tell me what this is?

```
$htmlcode = file_get_contents($url); 
$pattern = "/itemprop=\"description\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>(.*)\<li\>Taal:(.*)\<\/li\>(.*)\>(.*)\<‌​\/div\>/class=\"noscript\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>/sU";    
preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcode, $matches); # This is line 6:
```

I have already try to find something like this but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Please show the contents of $pattern and $htmlcode... There is probably something wrong in your $pattern...

Comment: give to us the $pattern contents

Comment: $htmlcode = file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = "/itemprop=\"description\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>(.*)\<li\>Taal:(.*)\<\/li\>(.*)\>(.*)\<\/div\>/class=\"noscript\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>/sU";

Comment: @bananaman $pattern is the most important in this case.. You can edit your question btw.. It makes it more readable for us than you pasting code in comments..

Comment: Oh, OK!
but what's the problem then?

Comment: The correct pattern is `'~itemprop="description">(.*)</div>(.*)<li>Taal:(.*)</li>(.*)>(.*)<‌​/div>/class="noscript">(.*)</div>~sU'`... but you shouldn't use regexes for html anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `$pattern` -- you haven't escaped all your slashes:

```
$pattern = "/itemprop=\"description\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>(.*)\<li\>Taal:(.*)\<\/li\>(.*)\>(.*)\<‌​\/div\>/class=\"noscript\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>/sU"
```

There's a slash in front of "class" that isn't escaped. The fix should be obvious...

You can make life much easier for yourself by using a different delimiter around your regex so you don't have to escape the slashes. Here's an example with `#` instead of `/`:

```
$pattern = "#itemprop=\"description\">(.*)</div>(.*)<li>Taal:(.*)</li>(.*)>(.*)<div class=\"noscript\">(.*)</div>#sU";
```

There are also a number of errors in your regex -- invalid html, etc., so it won't match anything in a valid html document. I've fixed most of them, but this part looks incorrect:

```
</li>(.*)>(.*)
```

I don't know what you're trying to match with the first capturing bracket set there, but you'll probably get something like `</ul` or `<li`.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'preg_match_all' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper.php on line 6 how do i solve this?

Comment: Did you escape the slashes? The code works for me. You would be much better off using a different delimiter so you don't have to escape all the slashes -- i'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @bananaman Could it be you forgot the semicolon (;) at the end of the $pattern line?